# IIS Multiple Server Farm Configuration?

Tags: iis, arr, web-farm, web-farm-framework

i got 10 IIS Server Farm and total 5 server on my configuration same machine. Each server farm has different arr configuration with different domains. What is the best aproch to configure application provisioning. Now i use one provision farm to sync all 5 servers and other farms for load balancing. Should i set all 10 farms with application provisioning or not ?

Comment: Web Farm Framework is considered obsolete, as Microsoft never updates it for IIS 10, https://blogs.iis.net/iisoobs

Comment: int this document it says "Web Farm Framework 1.1 no longer required – Application Request Routing no longer has a dependency on Web Farm Framework 1.1" we use "Web Farm 2.2"

Comment: That post lists all out-of-band IIS components Microsoft updated for IIS 10. Since Web Farm Framework 1.x/2.x are not in the post, they are assumed to be not compatible with IIS 10, and not supported there. You are supposed to migrate to Azure Stack.